# Wifi not working for ASUS NETBOOK X205TA using 17.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, acer

I have done some research and from what I can tell it is just Greek to me. I am brand new to linux and not super smart when it comes to this stuff. I just want to connect to wifi, but when I click the wifi icon my wifi does not show up at all.

So I did some research and some people showed some driver stuff , but you needed to connect an Ethernet which I cannot do.

As stated I have a acer netbook model: `X205TA`, I am running ubuntu version 17.04.

After some research I ran the command `rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and running `iwconfig` it says:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: You mean an Asus, not Acer?  Please post the entire output of rfkill list.  Nothing is expected on the loopback (lo) interface.

Comment: I don't see any wireless device.  Try posting lspci, looking for the network controller,  expecting something like an Ralink RT3290.  or lshw -c network, looking for the RT3290 and the rt2800pci driver.  The wireless light may or may not work. See if Fn F2  turns off/on the wireless.

Comment: It is the `brcmfmac` I would post the link to my other post about it, but last time I tried to do that it was prohibited and almost got my account banned

Comment: dmesg | grep firmware   to see if there is any error about missing firmware.  Also enter brcmfmac in the search bar for this site and look at the answers